# Changing the property from browser console doesn't fire the binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my controller code

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  window.foo = {bar: 'Foobar'};
  $scope.foo = foo;
});
```

Here is my template code

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{foo.bar}}!</p>
</body>
```

I tried to change the value of `foo.bar` from the chrome console as follows

```
foo.bar = "New Name"
```

But I don't see a change in the template, I'm a newbie at AngularJS. Can anybody explain what I am missing here ?

You can see the demonstration here http://plnkr.co/edit/MQv2wJdycAKN6MoajTkI?p=preview

***Note:** Since we cannot access global variables as it's a `iframe`, I'm using a `setTimeout`(I deliberately did not use `$timeout`) in this example*

Comment: It's because console is outside of angular you need to call $scope.$apply.

Comment: @jcubic I see, this is what I was missing. You can post it as an answer & I can accept it.

Comment: @people downvoting the question: Please post a comment on why you had to downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do something with a scope outside of angular you need to call $scope.$apply like this:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      foo.bar = "From settimeout";
    });
  }, 3000);
```